# Adding watches to Inotify in multi-threaded program

Tags: linux, multithreading, inotify

I wanted to use inotify for monitoring some files in my C program.

I am wondering if it is safe to have one thread reading from inotify descriptor (the one returned by `inotify_init`) thus blocking until some event happens, during this waiting there would be a possibility of adding new file to watch queue using `inotify_add_watch` during the other thread waiting period.

Do I need to synchronize those actions or is it safe to do such thing?

Comment: any news about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Don't have the exact answer, but I do know from experience that you can't even open files in another thread without triggering the read() in the thread you are using inotify.  I recall reading that you need to use inotify_init1() along with the IN_CLOEXEC flag to allow file io in other threads.  I'm not sure if that means you can actually use inotify in more than one thread simultaneously though.

Comment: The `IN_CLOEXEC` flag is useful when forking. @andna was asking for threads. I don't think this relates.